# Without computing $A^{-1}$, what is a good analytic upper-bound for $e^\top A^{-1} e$, where $A$ is positive-definite and $e = (1,\ldots,1)\;$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, singular-values

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ positive-definite matrix and let $e=(1,\ldots,1) \in \mathbb R^n$. Define $r(A) := e^\top A^{-1} e$. Note that we always have the trivial upper-bound $r(A) \le \lambda_\max(A^{-1})\|e\|^2 = n/\lambda_\min(A) =:r_0(A)$. Note that this bound is attained if $A$ is of the form $\alpha I_n$ with $\alpha>0$.

On the other hand, we always have
$$r_0(A) / r(A) \le r_0(A) / \lambda_\min(A^{-1})\|e\|^2 = \lambda_\max(A)/\lambda_\min(A)=:\kappa(A),
$$
where $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$.

> **Question.** Without computing the inverse of $A$, what is a a good analytic upper-bound for $r(A)$  which is better than the trivial upper-bound $r(A)\le r_0(A)$ ?

**Related question:** [Nontrivial lower-bound for $\inf_{x \in \Delta_n} \|Gx\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3878855/168758)

Comment: What is $r_0$? What if you have an $x$ with $||Ax-e||\leq \varepsilon$?

Comment: Omitted definition of $r_0(A)$; now fixed. I'm fine with anything which **provably** beats my "trivial" lower-bound $r_0(A)$ :)

Comment: How is this "attained when $A$ is diagonal"?

Comment: Indeed, that was an incorrect observation fixed (attained for matrices of the form $\alpha I_n$ with $\alpha>0$).

Comment: I don't think your upper bound is trivial if thought about correctly.  Writing making $A\propto I$ neuters the problem... instead consider $A^{-1}$ having $\mathbf 1$ as its dominant eigenvector, e.g. if $A^{-1}$ were doubly stochastic

Comment: Marginally related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307177/sum-of-elements-of-inverse-matrix

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't fit the bill. That thread is about numeracally solving $Ax = 1$, which is far from my interests here. But ya, related...